# Flutter define default value of a DateTime in constructor

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart

I have the state below and want to set the default for the DateTime in the constructor. I would like to have the current date as the default but I'm not sure if that is possible because it needs to be constant.
The `DateTime.now()` function or for example `DateTime.utc(1989, 11, 9)` also doesn't work but is there another way to assign a default DateTime?

```
class CreateDidState {
  final String firstname;
  final String lastName;
  final String email;
  final String phoneNumber;
  final DateTime dateOfBirth;
  final String sex;
  final String address;
  final String city;
  final String state;
  final String postalCode;
  final String country;

  CreateDidState(
      {this.firstname = "",
      this.lastName = "",
      this.email = "",
      this.phoneNumber = "",
      this.dateOfBirth = DateTime.now(), //The default value of an optional parameter must be constant.
      this.sex = "",
      this.address = "",
      this.city = "",
      this.state = "",
      this.postalCode = "",
      this.country = ""});
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The problem is that `DateTime.now()` is not a constant, which makes sense since constant means the value can be determined when compiling the program and we would therefore got the `DateTime` value for when we compiled the program if this constructor was marked `const`.

As the error you are getting are telling, you must use a constant evaluated value for default values. But we can do a trick here by doing something like this:

```
class CreateDidState {
  final String firstname;
  final String lastName;
  final String email;
  final String phoneNumber;
  final DateTime dateOfBirth;
  final String sex;
  final String address;
  final String city;
  final String state;
  final String postalCode;
  final String country;

  CreateDidState(
      {this.firstname = "",
      this.lastName = "",
      this.email = "",
      this.phoneNumber = "",
      DateTime? dateOfBirth,
      this.sex = "",
      this.address = "",
      this.city = "",
      this.state = "",
      this.postalCode = "",
      this.country = ""})
      : this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth ?? DateTime.now();
}
```

What we are doing here is are declaring the parameter `dateOfBirth` to be a nullable value (`DateTime?`). Since the default value of named parameters are `null` it means we don't need to specify any default value.

But we still want the class field `dateOfBirth` to be a non-nullable value. So I have removed the `this.` from the parameter so this constructor parameter have no relation to the class variable.

I have then added the following code to the class initializer part of the constructor (this code is running as part of creating the object and is allowed to initialize class variables with values):

```
      : this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth ?? DateTime.now();
```

What this means is that we want the class variable `dateOfBirth` (we are using `this.` to tell the two variables, with the same name, apart) to have the value of the expression `dateOfBirth ?? DateTime.now()`.

The `??` means that we returns the value at the left unless the value is `null`. If `null`, we returns the value to the right. So if `dateOfBirth` is `null` (which happens if we don't give the parameter a value since `null` is default) we uses the value created by `DateTime.now()`.

Comment: Can you please explain your answer? I really don't understand your format

Comment: @genericUser Sorry for the weak answer. Since I can see the problem (and my answer) have gotten a little popular, I think it have earned the right to get a proper explanation. Please tell me if I have missed any important details in my answer. :)

Comment: Thanks @julemand101! Great explanation!

Comment: @julemand101  How can i declare a birth_time variable in 24hour format along with date_of_birth here in this CreateDidState class, which one I should use DateTime or TimeOfDay??

Comment: @KJEjava48 I suggest creating a new question for that since it does not have much relation to this question or my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use my [const_date_time](https://pub.dev/packages/const_date_time) package to achieve this.

```dart
import 'package:const_date_time/const_date_time.dart';

class MyClass {
  const MyClass({
    this.date = const ConstDateTime(0),
  });
  
  final DateTime date;
}
```